# Does Advanced filter extract the data including formula?

Tags: excel

I have a dataset which is contains formulas. While Create advanced filter in excel as a result it shown only the value if the data no formula is there.

I want the formula also. Please anyone help me to do so.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show the formula of a cell, you might use the `=formulaText()` worksheet function, as you can see from the following screenshot:

```
Cell "D1" contains the formula "=1+1".
Cell "E1" contains the formula "=FormulaText(D1)".
```

Hereby the results:

[image]

[image]